# Tapestry: Can not show error for radiogroup

Tags: tapestry

There are zone > form > radiogroup in tml. Also present button at page.
My radiogroup is:

```
<t:radiogroup t:id="myRadioGroup" value="radioGroupValue" >
        <t:loop source="myRadioGroupList" value="radioGroupItem">
                <div class="radio">
                    <input t:type="radio" t:id="radio3" value="${radioGroupItem}"/>
                </div>
        </t:loop>
    </t:radiogroup>
<t:error for="myRadioGroup"/>
```

Java code:

```
@Component
private RadioGroup myRadioGroup;
@Property
private Integer radioGroupValue;

public Integer[] getMyRadioGroupList() {
    return new Integer[] { 1, 2 };
}

@Property
private Integer radioGroupItem;
```

On click button, executed my validation method, where I called:

```
myForm.recordError(myRadioGroup, "test");
```

But I do not see on page any error. If put to form `textfield` and add error for `textfield`, then error showing for `textfield`.

If I add `<t:errors/>`, then I see all errors: for `radiogroup` and for `textfield`.

But why error for `radiogroup` not visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it behave properly if you add a validate parameter to your radio group?

<t:radiogroup t:id="myRadioGroup" value="radioGroupValue" validate="required">

If so, then you may be hitting this Tapestry bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-1513